# Just Setup Postfix/Dovecot server. Mail appears to be being received but not appearing in Inbox

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail

So I just set up a little mail server on my VPS and it is sending mail just fine! The problem comes when it receives mail. The logs indicate that it retrieves the message, removes it from the queue and delivers it, but it never shows up!

Log:

```
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/smtpd[6345]: connect from mail.lcccorp.com[50.253.219.194]
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/smtpd[6345]: 302703EA47: client=mail.lcccorp.com[50.253.219.194]
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/cleanup[6349]: 302703EA47: message-id=<2c9ed3e8-c034-e2e9-7603-1c853e4f0d85@lcccorp.com>
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/qmgr[5793]: 302703EA47: from=<josh@lcccorp.com>, size=990, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/local[6350]: 302703EA47: to=<josh@joshshouse.us>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/qmgr[5793]: 302703EA47: removed
Aug 18 14:28:27 joshshouse postfix/smtpd[6345]: disconnect from mail.lcccorp.com[50.253.219.194]
```

There do not appear to be any errors.

`dovecot -n` result:

```
# 2.2.18: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.8 (0c4ae064f307+)
# OS: Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 15.10
auth_debug_passwords = yes
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap lmtp pop3"
ssl = no
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Here is my inbox:

[image: Empty Inbox screenshot]

If you need any more info I will provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix for those who need it. I had to change:

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
```

to

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

Simple fix. Silly mistake.